# Installed Ubuntu 20.04 a few weeks ago. Now stuck in loop

Tags: boot, dual-boot, kernel, 20.04

I recently installed 20.04 in dual boot on my surface book 2. I ran a few weeks without issue until yesterday. I tried booting to windows, and received an error then back to the boot selection screen.

Now Ubuntu is showing as the only boot selection, and I can't seem to get to the BIOS. If I select Ubuntu I get an error screen displaying:

```
(Error communicating to TMP chip) x 8
Kernel Panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
CPU: 1 PID: 1 COMM: swapper /0 Not Tainted 5.4.0-42-generic #46-Ubuntu
Hardware name: Microsoft Corporation Surface Book 2/Surface Book 2, BIOS 390.3192.768 03.24.2020
Call Trace:
dump_stack-0x6d/0x9a
panic+0x101/0x2e3
mount_block_root+0x23f/0x2e8
mount_root+0x38/0x3a
prepare_namespace+0x13f/0x194
kernel_init_freeable+0x231/0x255
? rest_init+0xb0/0xb0
kernel_init+0xe/0x100
ret_from_fork+0x35/0x40
Kernel Offset: 0xf600000 from 8xffffffff81000000 (relocation range: 0xffffffff00000000-0xffffffffbffffffff)
---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0, 0) ]---
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to askubuntu,

your problem looks like a kernel panic. See this [blog](https://www.geekswarrior.com/2019/07/solved-how-to-fix-kernel-panic-on-linux.html)
If possible, then start your last kernel which is possible to run.
Try to generate with `update-initramfs` new initramfs images for your kernel.
If it doesn't work, start Linux live distro and try it there.

Comment: It would be good if you could add details on how to do all the things you are suggesting